# deployment slot stops working after afew minutes?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a azure app servcice. next i created a  deployment slot , shown as web app called myapp/staging.
in visual studio, i deployed to the staging location.

it works for a couple minutes , but then it looks like it was never deployed - see picture
[image: no deploy]

Comment: looking at activity logs will give you more info, check this ink: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#monitor-swap

Comment: I don't see anything useful in Activity log. Every status = succeeded . 
example ;  List Web App Slot Security Sensitive Settings

any other things to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any error occurs during a slot swap, it's logged in D:\home\LogFiles\eventlog.xml. It's also logged in the application-specific error log.

During custom warm-up, the HTTP requests are made internally (without going through the external URL). They can fail with certain URL rewrite rules in Web.config. Just review your rewrite rules. 
As you're publishing it through VS, when you right click and select Publish Web on the left-hand side, you would find the settings tab. Select that. Then, expand the option under File Publish Options and check the Box for “Remove additional files at destination” – Review this option based on your requirement.

Also, just for additional information, an HTTP request to the application root is timed. The swap operation waits for 90 seconds for each HTTP request, and retries up to 5 times. If all retries are timed out, typically the swap operation is stopped.

Comment: this is my first time with staging .
in visual studio , i was publishing to the staging  url . Maybe instead i 'swap' ?

Comment: Yes, you swap and then check. Deployment slots are live apps with their own host names. App content and configurations elements can be swapped between two deployment slots, including the production slot. You can validate app changes in a staging deployment slot before swapping it with the production slot.
After a swap, the slot with previously staged app now has the previous production app. If the changes swapped into the production slot aren't as you expect, you can always perform the same swap immediately to get your "last known good site" back.